# Readonly getters VS property-like functions

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

With C#6 came some new features, including [getter-only auto-properties](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#getter-only-auto-properties)  and [property-like function members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-property-like-function-members).

I'm wondering what are the differences between these two properties? Is there any reason why I'd prefer one to another?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar {get;} = "Bar";
    public string Bar2 => "Bar2";
}
```

I know that `{get;} =` can only be set by a `static` call or a constant value and that `=>` can use instance members. But in my particular case, which one should I prefer and why?

Comment: Your claim about "I know that {get;} = can only be set by a static call" is incorrect. A property declared like that can only be set in the constructor, or via the initializer.

Comment: Oh that's right. I didn't make the link yet that those ways to set the read-only auto-property lead to the same result. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easiest to show them in terms of C# 1:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly string bar = "Bar";
    public string Bar { get { return bar; } }

    public string Bar2 { get { return "Bar2"; } }
}
```

As you can see, the first involves a field, the second doesn't. So you'd typically use the first with something where each object could have a different state, e.g. set in the constructor, but the second with something which is constant across *all* objects of this type, so doesn't need any per-object state (or where you're just delegating to other members, of course).

Basically, ask yourself which of the above pieces of code you would be writing if you didn't have C# 6 available, and choose the corresponding C# 6 path.